# .net files uploaded to online server but only shows code while running

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server

I have uploaded `Default.aspx`, `PrecompiledApp.config` and `web.config` to my file manager in server but when I call `Default.aspx` it displays code of file in the browser.

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_jpizvube" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

        function category_onclick() {

        }

        function fromM_onclick() {

        }

// ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat=server>
   <table border="2" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h3>Register New Customer</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td>Choose Category
</td>
<td>



    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td>Choose Subcategory
  </td>
   <td> 
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
           onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
       </asp:DropDownList>




  </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>Choose lowersubcategory
  </td>
   <td> 

       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
       </asp:DropDownList>

  </td>
  </tr>



    <tr>
    <td> Choose Location
    </td>
    <td>


        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Longitude<br/><br/>
    Latitude 
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Name
    </td>
    <td>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

    </td>
  </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>Image
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

    </td>
  </tr>


     <tr>
    <td>Contact Number
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Website
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </td>
  </tr>

 <!--<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>-->
  <tr>

  <td>Working Hours</td>
  <td>
  <label>Monday to Friday</label>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Value="6:00AM"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="6:30AM"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="7:00AM"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>



 <label>to</label>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>6:00AM</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>


  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Saturday</label>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />

      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>


 <label>to</label>

      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<label>Sunday</label>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />

      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
 <label>to</label>

      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>

  </td>
  </tr>


   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" Text="Register" 
            onclick="btn_Submit_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to deploy correctly, this code runs fine in visual studio when I try the same file after uploading to server it shows this source code in browser.

Comment: Is it a new server ? Have you run 'ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool' ? FYI - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: its old server but till now i havent used any .net project in server

Comment: Since this is your first time running .Net project in the server, try running ASP.NET IIS registration now and check again.

Comment: how to run ASP.NET IIS registration

Comment: where should i run it, please help me am new to .net

Comment: You need to publish the application in IIS Express and host the published folder in server

Comment: You're all assuming that the OP has placed this in the right file \ folder structure and has IIS running on the machine.  Also, the OP does not mention that he has deployed the bin directory either.  @princecherian take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt.aspx this will help you complete a successful deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server is not supporting .aspx MIME extension. you need to configure IIS. Please use this link - http://thesolving.com/server-room/how-to-install-and-configure-iis-on-windows-server-2012-r2/

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the ASP.NET Handler with IIS and for doing that you need to run aspnet_Regiis.exe , try running the command with administrator privileges . The location of the exe is within c:\Windows\Microsoft.NEt\Framework\v4.0.30319

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

You can read more about it from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx